# Passing external system command to run python proces with sys.process to scala program

Tags: scala, processbuilder

I've had no problem passing arguments to a python program called volatility in the past using sys.process._. However, I tried to add another argument and the program won't run.

Here is the code that worked:

```
psScan = Try(s"python vol.py -f $memFile --profile=$os psscan".!!.trim).getOrElse("Failed")
```

This code also worked:

```
s"python vol.py -f $memFile --profile=$os svcscan --verbose"
```

I'm not sure why the program won't accept the additional argument. Here are the different things I've tried that won't work.

```
psScan = Try(s"python vol.py -f $memFile --profile=$os --kdbg=$kdbg psscan".!!.trim)
psScan = Try(s"python vol.py -f $memFile --profile=$os -g $kdbg psscan".!!.trim)
psScan = Seq("python", "vol.py", "-f", memFile, s"--profile=$os", "--kdbg=$kdbg", "psscan").!!.trim
psScan = Seq("python", "vol.py", "-f", memFile, s"--profile=$os", "-g", kdbg, "psscan").!!.trim
```

I also tried to create an external environmental variable from the command line with "export VOLATILITY..", but that failed. (I know trying that was a hail mary).

Comment: If you want to see my full code, go to www.github.com/glassCodeBender/bbs

Comment: I solved this problem by having my program write a config file that is passed as an argument instead of passing the argument directly. Nevertheless, I'm curious to hear what other people think the problem is with the program. ProcessBuilder still baffles me.